# Search for Mentions of Topic with Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I'm looking to search for any of the following things, whichever seems to work the best:

```
Regular mentions of a topic ABC (ABC)
Hashtag mentions of a topic ABC (#ABC)
@ mentions of a topic ABC (@ABC)
```

How do I use the API to search this? Is there a specific way to form the URL to search for any one of these? For example, I'm currently using `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json` with a specified account.

EDIT: for example, I want to be able to get just the tweets that are shown on this page: https://twitter.com/search?q=%23FiveWordTechHorrors How do I do this from a developer point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%@&result_type=recent&count=%i", toBeSearched, count];
 url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] parameters:nil];
 [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
 [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
      //Rate Limit Reached
    } else if (error) {
         // Check if there was an error
    }
    // Check if there is some response data
    if (responseData) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
        // Do Whatever you want to do, the result is an array of 'tweet objects'
    }
}];
```

Comment: Ah, I thought I'd just get some sort of URL as a response, but it looks like you guessed Objective-C based on my history?
I'm gathering the URL from your code, though, and I'm trying it in mine. So you're saying something like `http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=ABC&result_type=recent&count=10`

Comment: And you can pass more parameters with url as specified here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Comment: Oh. I thought you asked it for iOS. Well, the url is the one you found in code.